# Metric for comparing binary images

Tags: image-processing, image-registration

I have two binary images which differ in a geometric transformation (for example, one image is a rotated version of the image) and I'd like to compare these two image for seeing if they are aligned. Which metric should I use?

Comment: What do you mean by a *"binary"* image please? Is it just a JPEG? Or PNG? Or is it a pure black and white image? Maybe you have one you can share and another one showing the sort of rotation you are talking about? What languages do you plan to use?

Comment: The images are just black and white. When I say rotation it was just for giving an example of geometric transformation, but what I want to do is trying to find a metric which returns me the degree of alignment of two images. Then, if I maximize or minimize this metric, I can align the images (it is a registration problem).

Comment: I think you will get better answers if you provide some representative examples.